# Add an auto fill search box on a sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, html, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I don’t have any experience with custom code and needed some help to upgrade a site.

I have a list [coreitemslookup] with three columns:

Title,
Description &
Related keywords

This list is on a SharePoint site added as a webpart.

I wanted to add a custom search (using script editor) on the site. It needs to have an auto-fill capability so that when you search, it gives suggestions, and displays matching keywords found in any of the columns in the list.

Would appreciate all the help I can get.

P.S I am using Sharepoint online on a modern page.

Comment: Have you checked this? -> https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/

Comment: https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-box/#query-suggestions This could be what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you, @jimas13. I have seen this before, but I could not figure out how I can have it search the list instead of SharePoint.